# NSNotificationCenter doesn't work in popup view(ios objC)

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsnotificationcenter

I'm working on a iPad project(xcode 7.21+iOS9) and `NSNotificationCenter` doesn't work.

When user open my app, the tab bar controller will appear.

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    if (false == [[MyClass sharedData] getLoginStatus])
    {
        LoginViewController *loginViewController = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"myCustomPopoverLoginVC"];
            loginViewController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;
            [self presentViewController:loginViewController animated:YES completion:^{

        }];
...
    }
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(notificationLogin:) name:@"afterLogin" object:nil];
    [super viewDidLoad];
...
}

-(void)notificationLogin:(NSNotification *)notification{
    NSLog(@"OhOhOh");
}
```

In my loginView,

```
-(IBAction)login:(id)sender{
    ...
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"afterLogin" object:nil];
    ...
}
```

Comment: Define "doesn't work".

Comment: Are you sure that you call `postNotification` after this view controller's `viewDidLoad` method is called?

Comment: Thanks rmaddy.I'm 100% sure postNotification is called,but I don't see "OhOhOh" in console.

Comment: You have to first add observer(addObserver) than only the post notification will work. I think in your case you are first posting the notification than you are adding observer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    if (false == [[MyClass sharedData] getLoginStatus])
    {
        LoginViewController *loginViewController = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"myCustomPopoverLoginVC"];
            loginViewController.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;
            [self presentViewController:loginViewController animated:YES completion:^{

        }];
...
    }
}

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    // Add log here to check when its called
    -------> NSLog("Add Observer");
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(notificationLogin:) name:@"afterLogin" object:nil];
    [super viewDidLoad];
...
}

-(void)notificationLogin:(NSNotification *)notification{
    NSLog(@"OhOhOh");
}
```

then add another log here :

```
-(IBAction)login:(id)sender{
    ...
    -------> NSLog("Post notification");
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] postNotificationName:@"afterLogin" object:nil];
    ...
}
```

So you can check what called first. Then refer @Sandeep Kumar comment :))
[NSNotificationCenter doesn't work in popup view(ios objC)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36000496/nsnotificationcenter-doesnt-work-in-popup-viewios-objc#comment59653796_36000496)

Comment: Put a NSLog inside "viewDidLoad" and then another NSLog inside "(IBAction)login:(id)sender". Then you'll be definitely sure whether the observer is registered before the notification is fired.